# Splitting a singly linked list multiple times

Tags: java, split, linked-list

I've been working with linked lists and have been trying to split them. If i had methods to add nodes and to print the list such as A to add and p to print and s to split. I want to split the linked list once or twice or more times at a given index.
For example if I had an input like:

> A 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> s 2 4 6
>
> p

I'd want my output to be:

> 1 2

I know how to join split lists but I really want to know how to split them like this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which node you want to split at?

Comment: sorry bout dat, I just edited it to make it more readable. I want to split it at the specified indexes eg) s 2 4 6 - split at indexes 2 4 and 6.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for the clarification. I have posted some suggestions and hints as an answer. Also, remember that SO is a professional website. Shorthand such as "dat" comes across as unprofessional. Please take the time to use correct English grammar and spelling as we continue to discuss your queston.

Answer (score 0):

¿Have you tried API class [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)?

Comment: -1 The OP is obviously implementing their own linked list as a learning exercise (maybe as a class project).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you simplify your problem as much as you can by splitting the list at a single element. You probably need a method called `split()`. What parameters does this method need? What should its return type be? What action does the method do? Are there any side-effects?

In order to create a solution, you need to clearly understand the problem to begin with. Answering these questions can hopefully get you started in the right direction. Let me know what you come up with and we can go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If you scroll all the way to the bottom of my code, there's a skeleton of a split method that I started on but I don't know how to finish it.

Comment: @user2375038 My questions are intended for you to back away from the code to some extent. Describe *in English* what the parameters and the return type are and what they represent. Also describe *in detail* steps the method should take to accomplish the task. Feel free to add this information to your original question.

Comment: p.s. For now I suggest you just think about splitting the list *once*.

Comment: I see, you're right I was a bit too eager. But even if I did want to split it once, the only method I can think of is to loop up until the specified index and delete any remaining nodes. But I'm not even sure how to start that.

Comment: @user2375038 "loop up until the specified index and delete any remaining nodes" This is heading in the right direction, although you don't want to permanently delete the remaining nodes. Instead you need to cut the list in two and have some way of keeping track of the beginning of the remaining nodes for the second list. You say you don't know where to start. Do you know how to make a while or for loop?